# Why GoDaddy custom domain redirects to Heroku's appid.herokuapp.com?

Tags: godaddy, mediawiki, heroku

I am trying to setup a [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) with Heroku.

Here is the setup I did for my wikinames.org domain in my GoDaddy account:

- DNS zone:

  - @    A    50.63.202.1
  - www    CNAME    myappid.herokuapp.com
- Forwarding (for naked domain support):

  - from: http://wikinames.org to: http://www.wikinames.org, 301 (permanent), forward only

Once I go to http://www.wikinames.org, I observe the following:

1. request remote address: *23.21.223.98:80*, status Code: *301 Moved Permanently*
2. response header: *Location: https://wikinames-org.herokuapp.com/index.php?title=Main_Page* (I've installed MediaWiki, but 
   `$wgServer` there is equal to `http://www.wikinames.org`).

Why does it redirect me to wikinames-org.herokuapp.com?

Upd. Looks like it happens because of [ip 50.63.202.1](https://www.godaddy.com/help/updating-your-domain-names-ip-address-for-forwarding-5289) used. But if I delete this record, then naked domain stops working, but `www` version still redirects to https://wikinames-org.herokuapp.com.

Upd2. Looks like enabling of [masking](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422) could help me, but seems it will work only with `www` case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with the MediaWiki installed. `$wgServer` there was equal to `wikinames-org.herokuapp.com` initially. I thought that I've changed that, but looks like the change wasn't uploaded to Heroku.